# UILabel truncate middle lines in multi-line label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel that has 3 lines max. Here is the code:

```
_testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
_testLabel.text = @"Line 11111111111111\nLine 2\nLine 3";
_testLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
_testLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
[_testLabel sizeToFit];
_testLabel.width -= 5;
```

By calling sizeToFit and then subtracting 5, I cause line 1 to wrap. This in turn pushes line 3 outside of the allowed bounds, so at the end of "Line 2" there is a "..." and line 3 is not shown.

Instead of wrapping line 1 and truncating line 3, what I really want it to truncate line 1. This way, any lines that are too long to fit in the specified width will be truncated and NOT wrapped.

Is there a way to achieve this?

The best I can think of is to split the string at every '\n' char, and have a separate UILabel for each line with numberOfLines set to 1 for each.

EDIT:

To be more clear, here is what the label looks like with the example code above:

```
Line
11111111111111
Line 2...
```

And here is what I would like it to look like:

```
Line 11111111111...
Line 2
Line 3
```

Comment: *split the string at every '\n' char, and have a separate UILabel for each line with numberOfLines set to 1 for each.* -- yep, I think you really want multiple UILabels in this case.

Comment: Have you tried using `NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle` for `lineBreakMode`?

Comment: Yeah I tried NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle, and this isn't what it does sadly. It's looking like splitting it into multiple labels is going to be necessary. The only other option would be subclassing UILabel and over-riding the draw method myself... Which is clearly a lot more work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the enumerators for NSLineBreakMode

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLineBreakMode

Comment: None of these options can do what I need, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to calculate the size of the UILabel before you set its text, then tweak your line break settings.

See NSString's method:
`- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right . You need only one other line .

set "adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth" with "false" in order to prevent the label from fitting width by changing font size.